# PHP : Function in preg_replace says that the function was already declared

Tags: php, regex

**The Function:**

```
function doSomething($url){
    $url = "<a href=\"{$url}\" target=\"blank\" title=\"{$url}\">{$url}</a>";
    return $url;
}
```

**The replacement**

```
$content = preg_replace("#(http:\/\/+[^\s]+)#ie","doSomething('$1')", $content);
```

**The Problem:**

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare
>   doSomething() (previously declared
>   in
>   http://example.com/test.php:69)
>   in http://example.com/test.php
>   on line 69

**Note:** The current function does not represent my real function, I know that for this situation I don't need any functions but in my real code I need. But this is a better example also.

Comment: Do you have to enclose your function in quotes?

Comment: Yes @shady, because I'm inside a `preg_replce` and I use the `e` modifier in the pattern. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's because the function was already defined in a prior function call (That's the danger in declaring a function inside of another function).  There are a few options.

Conditionally declaring the function

```
if (!function_exists('doSomething')) {
    function doSomething($url)...
}
```

Declaring an anonymous function:

PHP 5.3+ :

```
$callback = function($url) {
    //...
}
```

PHP 5.2+ :

```
$callback = create_function('$url', '//...');
```

Using a class:

```
class foo {
    public function doReplace($string) {
        $callback = array($this, 'doSomething');
        // Do your matching here
    }
    public function doSomething($url) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Also, I'd suggest not using the `e` modifier for the regex (it's just not necessary, and it's basically just `eval`, which is typically seen as evil).  You should instead just use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

Assuming `$callback` is a valid callback:

```
$callback = function($match) {
    $url = $match[1];
    //... Do stuff here
}
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string);
```

Comment: @ircmaxell Hi! Thanks very much for your answer! I think this will help me a lot.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3 but I get this error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in example.com/test.php on line 83` Also I have `Dreamweaver CS5` what highlights the anonymous function as invalid. I've read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php and I made it as it writes but I don't know what is the problem :S

Comment: Like I said, don't use the `e` modifier, and pass the callback as a varaible to `preg_replace_callback`:  `$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string);` where `$callback` is the anonymous function directly.  There's no need to cast anything to objects...  And I would suggest getting a decent IDE for writing PHP (Dreamweaver is not a development environment)...

Comment: The replacement: `$content = preg_replace_callback("#(http:\/\/+[^\s]+)#i", $do('$1'), $content);` The function: `$do = function($url){
  $url = "<a href=\"{$url}\" target=\"blank\" title=\"{$url}\">{$url}</a>";
  return $url;
 };` the error: `Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, '<a href="$1" target="blank" title="$1">$1</a>', to be a valid callback in C:\wamp\www\includes\all_news.php on line 83`

Comment: You don't need to add the `('$1')` to the `$do` variable...  You should just do: `$do = function($match){ $url = $match[1]; $url = "<a href=\"{$url}\" target=\"blank\" title=\"{$url}\">{$url}</a>"; return $url; };` And then call it with `$content = preg_replace_callbac($regex, $do, $content);`...

Comment: `$do` is just a [callback](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).  The function it "points" to gets called for each match with the match array as the first parameter (A native PHP array, with `0` matching the entire match, `1` being the first sub-pattern, etc)...  Take a read through the `preg_replace_callback` docs that I linked to in my answer for more info on what's going on...

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!! Blessing to you! :D

Answer (score 0):

As they say, doSomething has already been defined. Use doSomething2 :)

Answer (score -2):

Well... error message says the problem. You have a declaration for `doSomething()` function several times.

Check out line 69 of `test.php` and try to comment declaration.

Comment: @Otar I don't use more than once `doSomething()`. I think the problem comes for the `e` modifier which enables `preg_replace` to use the function multiple times, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: the problem is obviously not that `doSomething()` is declared more than once, since the error message says that it's declared twice on the same line, i.e. the line with `preg_replace()`

Comment: @Frxstrem: how do you know the error is on the same line as the preg_replace()?

Comment: @hopeseekr: okay, I do not exactly know, but since the first declaration and the second declaration are on the same line, I assumed it was not because of a double declaration, which from my point of view seems like a pretty good assumption too. double declarations happen **very rarely** on the same line

Comment: @Frxstrem - Double declarations happen very rarely on the same line, unless a file with a function declaration is included twice in another file.